# RavenDB: Find closest date in range

Tags: datetime, ravendb

Im trying to query for documents closest to the date i pass to my query.
The problem is RavenDB cannot translate my query:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot understand how to translate Abs

Here is the query I am trying:

```
_session.Query<ExchangeRate>().OrderBy(d => Math.Abs((date - d.TimeStamp).Ticks)).First();
```

If RavenDB cant translate these Math functions, what other options are there to write this type of query ?

**Update 1**

Based on Ayende's answer i tried the following which seems to work, not sure if its the best solution. It also takes into account if the date is out of the bounds of available data, it just returns null to be handled by calling code.

```
        var rateBefore = _session.Query<ExchangeRate>()
            .Where(x => x.TimeStamp.Date <= date.Date)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var rateAfter = _session.Query<ExchangeRate>()
            .Where(x => x.TimeStamp.Date >= date.Date)
            .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (rateBefore == null || rateAfter == null) 
            return rateBefore ?? rateAfter;

        var beforeDiff = Math.Abs(rateBefore.TimeStamp.Ticks - date.Ticks);
        var afterDiff = Math.Abs(rateAfter.TimeStamp.Ticks - date.Ticks);

        return beforeDiff <= afterDiff ? rateBefore : rateAfter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require to go over all the data in the db.
Instead, do two queries.
One to get the first one equal or less than the date.
One to get the first one equal or greater than the date.

Then pick the closest.

Comment: I updated my post with a solution based on your answer. Can you see any issues with this or improvements ?

Comment: You can take it a step further by using lazy queries, so you'll only do a single request to the server .See: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-perform-queries-lazily